# How to get difference from GMT time zone to my current local(GWT)?

Tags: java, datetime, gwt, datetime-format, datetimeoffset

I have some minor problems with showing time in my GWT application. I want when e.g User creates new item(in my time say 10:00) on grid to be shown time as 17/4/2018 10:00 + GMT 02:00(because my time zone is +2 in compare with GMT). This is my part of code when I do formatting:

```
import java.util.Date;

import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.TimeZone;

import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat;

    public static String formatDateTime(Date d) {
            if (d == null) {
                return NONE;
            }

            TimeZone gmt = TimeZone.createTimeZone(0);
            return DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZZ").format(d, gmt);
        }
```

But with this code I have time in GMT but this part after + is always 00:00 (like `17/4/2018 08:13 + 00:00`). How could I change that to be like `17/4/2018 10:13 GMT + 02:00` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right...10:13 GMT + 02:00 is right choice I will refactor my question..

Comment: Not knowing GWT very well, isn’t it just a matter of passing the user’s time zone as the second argument to `format()` instead of `gmt`?